# Twitter Bootstrap Carousel overriding left and right button

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

In Twitter Bootstrap Carousel.

I have 6 items in my carousel. Depends on the user input I need to show only 5 or 6 slide. For this behavior I need to skip the slide while use clicks left and right arrow in carousel. Is there is way to override left and right arrow in carousel  .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just:

1. Check current slide id
2. Add +/- 1 depends on current id (left/right side) to avoid showing it up

From carousel dosc:

```
 .carousel(number)
```

Cycles the carousel to a particular frame (0 based, similar to an array).

```
.carousel('prev')
```

Cycles to the previous item.

```
.carousel('next')
```

Cycles to the next item.

Hope it helps to solve your problem.

Comment: Is it possible to override left and rigth arrow as well?

Comment: Maybe its not the best way but yes you can, here is working example: http://jsfiddle.net/JG2PW/ when you click on left arrow it will be always displaying slide with id = 0